# Blocked by CORS policy because of a 302 Moved Temporarily

Tags: javascript, rest, cors

I'm using the [Bullhorn REST API](https://bullhorn.github.io/Getting-Started-with-REST/) from my website.
In my javascript code, I have the following:

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
var requestOptions = {
  method: "GET",
  redirect: "follow",
  headers: myHeaders,
};
const url_part1 = "https://auth.bullhornstaffing.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=";
const url_part2 = "&response_type=code&username=";
const url_part3 = "&password=";
const url_part4 = "&action=Login";
const full_url =
  url_part1 +
  client_id +
  url_part2 +
  username +
  url_part3 +
  password +
  url_part4;
response = await fetch(full_url, requestOptions);
```

If the `client_id`, the `username` or the `password` are wrong, I get a 200 OK response and I don't have any problem, even if I don't allow CORS (which I'm not too sure I understand why).

However, if they are correct, I get redirected with a 302 Moved Temporarily response. And I have the standard:

```py
Access to fetch at 'https://welcome.bullhornstaffing.com/?code=*************' (redirected from 'https://auth.bullhornstaffing.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=*******&response_type=code&username=*****&password=******&action=Login') from origin '*****' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

So I tried various answers I found online, for example, adding:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:3000"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
</IfModule>
```

to `.htmaccess`.

I do now see in the response headers of the request that javascript initiates with `fetch`:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin, highLevelCallStack, uniqueCallId, x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *******
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

But I'm still redirected, and on the second response header of the second page to which I'm redirected, these headers disappear. Which I assume is the reason why it's raising the error I shared above.

What should I do? I feel like I've tried so many things (`functions.php`, etc ... - I basically read 20 stackoverflow posts) and I couldn't make any work.

EDIT: additional information:

I've tried locally by designing my chrome extension to make the calls and it works when I add `"host_permissions": ["https://*/", "http://*/"]` to the `manifest.json` even though I don't have any of the headers `Access-Control-Allow-*` in my request headers. I'm unsure why this is so. The only other difference I have in the request headers is `Sec-Fetch-Site: none` locally and `Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site` on my website. However, I'm unsure how those work and how to change those headers.

Comment: There may be nothing you can do other than complain to the provider or start using your own proxy.

Comment: I would assume this is such a big API that some users managed to make it work? Or maybe it's actually not a very used one?

Comment: I've tried locally by designing my chrome extension to make the calls and it works when i add `"host_permissions": ["https://*/", "http://*/"],` to the `manifest.json` even though I don't have any of the headers `Access-Control-Allow-*` in my request headers. I'm unsure why this is so. The only other difference I have in the request headers is `Sec-Fetch-Site:
none` locally and `Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site` on my website. However, I'm unsure how those work.